# use fancybox iframe to login wordpress, then reload original page

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

On one of my sites I've added a custom div to the footer.php which goes to the login page for the wordpress site:

```
<p id="login" align="left"><?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {  ?>
   <a href="http://mydomain.com/wp-login.php?action=logout&_wpnonce=518b41a419" alt="logout">[-] logout</a>
<?php } else { ?> 
   <a href="http://mydomain.com/wp-login.php" alt="login">[+] members login</a>
<?php } ?></p>
```

I use the "Fancybox for Wordpress" plugin to load iframes for contact forms and the like.
I was wondering how I can make the login show in an iframe, so that when the login is successful, the iframe closes and the page they were on reloads (so they're not taken to the cms).

Comment: What have you tried doing? You could simply create a login page, point Fancybox to load that page via ajax, or as an iframe `hint: use type: iframe/ajax`, to present a form. [Having a read over this document](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon) tells us that there are default variables you can assign, which are `log`, `pwd`, and `rememberme`. You would simply need to [register your ajax call](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)) so it knows how to route the request. From there, you can return true/false, check in javascript, and redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need an iframe to accomplish this. It sounds like you just want a login that leaves people on the current page. The problem with using an iframe is that the rest of the interaction will then happen inside that iframe. Try this instead: just instruct WordPress to return the user to the current page after logging them in.

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_login_url(get_permalink()); ?>" title="Login">Login</a>
```

More info at http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_url.

Comment: that'll do the job.  no need to complicate things by loading it in a lightbox.   It's still the same amount of mouse clicks.   Thanks!